# Как удалять данные в бд за последний час/месяц(Python)

Tags: python

```
def init_db(force: bool = False):
    conn = get_connection()

    c = conn.cursor()

    if force:
        c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_message')

    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_message (
                id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                text    TEXT NOT NULL,
                date DATETIME  NOT NULL
              )
        ''')

    conn.commit()

def add_message(user_id: int, first_name: str, text: str, date: datetime):
    conn = get_connection()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO user_message (user_id, first_name, text, date) Values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
              (user_id, first_name, text, date))
    c.execute('')
    conn.commit()
```

Main.py(сохранение записей из телеграм чата):

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(message: types.Message):
    add_message(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name, message.text,
                message.date)
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name
```

Что нужно прописать во второй **c.execute('')** ?

Нужно удалять данные за последний месяц или неделю при вызове данной функции **add_message**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последний месяц:

```sql
DELETE FROM user_message WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

Неделя:

```sql
DELETE FROM user_message WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days'
```

Ещё замечу, что вы записываете даты без информации о часовых поясах, и при этом дата при записи сообщения судя по всему генерируется через Python.

Если вы совершенно уверенны в том, что вы делаете, то тогда всё нормально. Если же нет, то перепишите код, используя нормальный тип в базе данных, и определите в базе данных значение по умолчанию для даты.